# Protractor - click causing angular to freeze

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm having trouble with a protractor test.

#### Overview of the test

1. Click button to show a form
2. Fill out the form
3. Click another button to save the form - this should call a function in one of my controllers that makes an http call and then reloads some models on the page.

When clicking the final "save" button, everything seems to freeze and the attached ng-click function never seems to get called. I don't see any errors in the console when I use `browser.pause`. I can see that the button is in fact clicked, but at that point, nothing seems to happen.

Final button definition:

```
this.addConfigFilterLineButton = element(by.css('[ng-click="cflCtrl.create();"]'));
```

Function that fills out the form:

```
this.addNewConfigFilterLine = function (cb) {
  var self = this;
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

  browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);')
  .then(function(){
    self.newConfigFilterLineButton.click();

    // code that fills out the form

    self.addConfigFilterLineButton.click();

    browser.waitForAngular()
    .then(function(){
      deferred.fulfill();
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

Spec

```
it('should allow creating a new ConfigFilterLine', function (done) {
  var length;
  settingsPage.configFilterLines.count()
  .then(function(count){
    length = count;
    return settingsPage.addNewConfigFilterLine();
  })
  .then(function(){
    expect(settingsPage.configFilterLines.count()).to.eventually.equal(length+1);

    done();
  });
});
```

I've tried with `browser.waitForAngular` and without it, and it doesn't seem to matter. When the button is clicked, nothing happens.

Any ideas would be helpful. Let me know if there's more info I can provide.

Comment: Have you noticed anything strange in *elementExplorer*?

Comment: When I jump into elementExplorer, I see the same behavior. I can select the element and tell it to click, but when I do that, the button stays depressed as if the click is stuck. No errors in the console or anything.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work with elementExplorer, I guess that the issue is with the Angular code itself.

Comment: It works when I'm just manually testing just fine. Just an issue when doing it through protractor.

Comment: Just for kicks, I tried adding the `.click()` command twice. And now everything is working fine. So for some reason, the initial click isn't registering all the way, but clicking a second time sends the command all the way through...not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Actually, after playing with it some more, this only works sometimes. About 2/3 of the time, adding the second click makes the test pass. The other third of the time, protractor bombs on the second click saying the element is not clickable at position... Totally lost at this point

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`this.addConfigFilterLineButton = element(by.css('[ng-click="cflCtrl.create();"]'));`

try something more like this:

`this.addConfigFilterLineButton = element(by.id('id-of-final-button'));`

My guess is that Protractor isn't correctly finding "addConfigFilterLineButton".

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Tried using `by.id` and `by.partialButtonText` and still have the same issue. When I watch the test run, I can see that the button gets depressed like it's getting clicked. But after that nothing happens. It's worth noting that I just wrote another test for deleting a line and the same thing happens after clicking the confirm delete prompt. Everything just stops.